# Issues with devanagari package

Tags: fonts, packages, minionpro

I am experiencing an issue with the pagackage **devanagari** in conjunction with **MinionPro**. Specifically, the font in the "list of figures", the "table of contents" or "list of tables" is automatically set to the default one, rather than "Minion Pro". Let us consider the following LaTeX source code:

```
\def\DevnagVersion{2.15}
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{devanagari}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
%
\chapter{A chapter}
Lets write in devanagari
{\dn \7{j}gAw}
%
\chapter{Another chapter}
Hello, world!
%
\end{document}
```

The outcome is shown in the picture below:
[image: the issue]

The remaining part of the output file is not shown. The issue just affects the above mentioned elements.

Comment: Are you running it through XeLaTeX? Also do you preprocess the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `devanagari` package defines a helper macro `\NormalFont`, that it calls at suitable places. Such a command presets the font family to `cmr` (and the font encoding to OT1).

```
\def\DevnagVersion{2.15}
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tgtermes} % or other font package
\usepackage{devanagari}

% change the defaults of devanagari.sty
\let\DNrmdefault\rmdefault
\let\DNencodingdefault\encodingdefault % important if you use T1

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
Lets write in devanagari
{\dn \7{j}gAw}

\chapter{Another chapter}
Hello, world!

\end{document}
```

Here is the output of `pdffonts`, which shows no trace of Computer Modern:

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
TPMQYZ+TeXGyreTermes-Bold            Type 1            yes yes no       4  0
PGZPRI+TeXGyreTermes-Regular         Type 1            yes yes no       5  0
HKXQVU+Velthuis-dvng10               Type 1            yes yes no      11  0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very elegant solution, but it is a workaround. I used `palatino` instead of Minion Pro which is not installed of my computer. The idea is to redefine the fonts, by hand - that's why I call it inelegant.

[image]

```
%\def\DevnagVersion{2.15}
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
%
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{devanagari}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont} % chapter titles
             {\usefont{T1}{bch}{b}{n}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont} % section titles
             {\usefont{T1}{bch}{m}{n}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont} % subsection titles
             {\usefont{T1}{bch}{m}{n}\selectfont} 
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont} % chapter page numbers
             {\usefont{T1}{bch}{b}{n}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont} % section page numbers
             {\cftsecfont} 
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont} % subsection page numbers
             {\cftsubsecfont}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
Lets write in devanagari
{\dn \7{j}gAw}

\chapter{Another chapter}
Hello, world!
\section{Whatever}

\end{document}
```